# Where are the life cycle events of ASP.Net declared? (NOT the event handlers)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events, global-asax, eventhandler

I have an ASP.Net MVC application.
Inside there is the famous Global.asax (I didn't touch it):

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Now, people said this is the event which
is being fired when the application starts.
I'm sorry but what I see here is not an event - This is a method.
I believe there is an event somewhere that is being fired, and is pointing on this METHOD (so this method is an event handler. Am I wrong?)

My Q is where is the event itself? I looked for it in all the solution and didn't find it.

Comment: Your application inherits `System.Web.HttpApplication` class, I guess all events are declared inside it. `Application_Start` is an event handler, you are right here

Comment: If you want to dig deeper, check the [Call Stack](https://i.imgur.com/QuSlhZF.png) and then follow those methods in the `HttpApplication` class on [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpApplication.cs,c967151e40a6e5a4).

Comment: well, there does seem to be more to this than I had initially thought... but, It's hard to agree to the premise that there is a life cycle of events here beyond initialization and activation of these `HttpApplication` instances by ASP.NET, more specifically `ApplicationManager`.  In regards to `Application_Start`, it's probably neither an event nor event handler (no event is raised that it handles).  There is a runtime compilation on HttpApplication, so It's probably an optional method that is invoked in the `Init` event handling scope...

Comment: but my probabilities are not warranted.. this a question and premise that could use some insider information.

Answer (score 0):

Well after getting the stack trace the leads to the call to Application_Start,I found it was like

```
at WebApplication1.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Users\Elite\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication1\Global.asax.cs:line 16
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InvokeMethodWithAssert(MethodInfo method, Int32 paramCount, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ProcessSpecialRequest(HttpContext context, MethodInfo method, Int32 paramCount, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs, HttpSessionState session)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)
```

This [link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/HttpApplicationFactory.cs,c6b3d6f246cf63f3) contains the source code for the whole thing,

```
private MethodInfo _onStartMethod;
```

You are probably interested in the above field, it gets set in this [method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/HttpApplicationFactory.cs,b0a90d9df37ace19,references), if u would spend a couple of minutes with this code u will find that what MVC is doing is scanning for methods existing in the global.ascx file (which is actually a class inheriting HttpApplication class) using reflection of course

Also if you observed the stack trace , u will find a call to the method `RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS` , which I am guessing is the answer to your question:"where does events come from"